# Django: singleton per request?

Tags: django

We have a wrapper around a suds (SOAP) request, that we use like this throughout our app:

```
from app.wrapper import ByDesign
bd = ByDesign()
```

Unfortunately, this instantiation is made at several points per request, causing suds to redownload the WSDL file, and I think we could save some time by making `bd = ByDesign()` return a singleton.

Since suds is not threadsafe, it'd have to be a singleton per request.

The only catch is, I'd like to make it so I don't have to change any code other than the `app.wrapper.ByDesign` class, so that I don't have to change any code that calls it.  If there wasn't the 'singleton per request' requirement, I'd do something like this:

```
class ByDesignRenamed(object):
    pass

_BD_INSTANCE = None
def ByDesign():
    global _BD_INSTANCE
    if not _BD_INSTANCE:
       _BD_INSTANCE = ByDesignRenamed()
    return _BD_INSTANCE
```

But, this won't work in a threaded server environment.  Any ideas for me?

Comment: I'm not sure, but could you store the instance in the session? The session dictionary should accept any pickleable Python object; that way you could have a singleton per session, so to speak.

Comment: Right, but then I'd have to change all the code accessing it

Comment: It is not pretty, but letting the constructor/call accepting parameters (e.g. a request object) and then check for a valid instance in should be not too difficult from the refactoring side. An other option would be to persist the object somewhere else, memcache, (key-value-)DB or even filesystem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out threading.local(), which is somewhere between pure evil and the only way to get things going.  It should probably be something like this:

```
import threading

_local = threading.local()

def ByDesign():
    if 'bd' not in _local.__dict__:
       _local.bd = ByDesignRenamed()
    return _local.bd
```

Further reading:

- [Why is using thread locals in Django bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227180/why-is-using-thread-locals-in-django-bad)
- [Thread locals in Python - negatives, with regards to scalability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103741/thread-locals-in-python-negatives-with-regards-to-scalability)